# Aspectj cflow performance issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, aspectj

Looks like cflow pointcut will inject codes to every line of the target project. My Android project has about 80,000 lines. And when trying to run the app with eclipse, it failed.

> "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap
>   space".

And I looked at the sources, each line is marked as advised by my cflow pointcut, which might be the reason that java heap space is out of usage.
I have increased the heap size in eclipse.ini as below, but still failed.

> ...
>   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 512M 
>   -showsplash com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
>   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 512m
>   -vmargs
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
>   -Xms512m 
>   -Xmx1024m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
> ...

So my question is that how to solve such problem?  Should I give up cflow? Or there is a better way to use it?

My intention is to produce a function call tree based on user actions. I create the UI actions pointcut, then use cflow to get the function call trees.

My pointcut is as below:

```
 pointcut cflowOnClick():
cflow(execution(public void onClick(View)))`
```

Comment: what is your intent with the pointcut? most likely you do not intend to use cflow.

Comment: I am trying to produce a function call tree.

Comment: a better bet would be to use `around`, add the node in the tree, and then `proceed`.  cflow and cflowbelow, pick out every pointcut (like you mentioned). they are useful in when you want to isolate a function call from the call site when the program is below some control flow, it is hardly every used alone. you can use `around` with wildcards (or `before` since you are not changing args), and cflow together if you are trying to produce the callgraph for everything below this method.